# How do I set an entity base field as NOT NULL?

Tags: 8, entities, database

When creating custom entities in Drupal 8, you define a bunch of fields in `baseFieldDefinitions()` on your entity class, like this:

```
  <?php
  public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    $fields = parent::baseFieldDefinitions($entity_type);

    $fields['postal_code'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel('PLZ')
      ->setDescription(t('Postal code.'))
      ->setSetting('unsigned', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'number',
      ])
      ->setRequired(TRUE);

    return $fields;
  }
```

However, these fields, despite being marked required, are defined as nullable in the database.

There’s no `->setNullable(FALSE)` or similar method on `BaseFieldDefinition`. So how else do you make Drupal generate the schema correctly?

Comment: you can always do it in a hook update `db_change_field('foo', 'bar','bar', array('type' => 'serial', 'not null' => TRUE) `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for that at the moment, every field that is specified as a key happens to be set to not null, but that's IMHO actually a bug and I would not rely on that.

Instead, the only thing you can do is provide a storage schema handler and customize the schema there.

See \Drupal\node\NodeStorageSchema::getSharedTableFieldSchema() for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I’ll try to create a coherent bug report based on this.

Comment: There will be a new method `BaseFieldDefinition::setStorageRequired()`. As Berdir mentioned there is no API yet but there is work in progress on an API in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2841291

Comment: It doesn't appear setStorageRequired() can make a field nullable, as of today.